# Do I need to do anything before sending data to a printer over PyParallel?

Tags: python, printing, parallel-port

I am trying to use PyParallel to send data to a printer.

According to the [GitHub readme](https://github.com/pyserial/pyparallel), the basic code is :

```
import parallel
p = parallel.Parallel()  # open LPT1 or /dev/parport0
p.setData(0x55)
```

But that doesn't work, must I do something (like sending a special code or something) before sending data.

I never used a parallel port before.
I have seen [this example](http://www.logix4u.net/parallel-port/parallel-port/15-a-tutorial-on-parallel-port-interfacing) in C but it's not about printers.
I have also seen [this exemple](http://www.bristolwatch.com/pport/) in python and he send the data directly, but again it's not about printers.

EDIT: Here the full code that I tried :

```
#coding: utf-8

try:
    import parallel
except OSError as e:
    raise
else:   
    p = parallel.Parallel()  # open LPT1 or /dev/parport0
    print p.getInError() # print 1
    print p.getInSelected() # print 1
    print p.getInPaperOut() # print 0
    print p.getInAcknowledge() #print 1
    print p.getInBusy() # print False
    p.setAutoFeed(0)
    p.setInitOut(0)
    p.setData(0x55)
    p.setData(0x0D)
    p.setData(0x0A)
```

I know the printer is working, when i execute my code, the printer doesn't do anything, the get functions print something (I commented the code) but I don't understand what it means.

Comment: It doesn't work how? Your example only sends one character *0x55` (which is the ASCII character `U`) to the port/printer. You may need to add a newline (`x0A`) or a carriage-return + newline (`0x0D`, `0x0A`) to end the line because the printer may be buffering characters until it receives a complete lines-worth of data. It's also likely your printer accepts special character sequences to control it — for things like making characters bold or italic— consult the manual that came with the printer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm sorry I forgot to say that I added carriage-return and new line to my code. I'm gonna update the question with more information.

Comment: Don't forget to specify how it's not working.

Comment: Do you see what could be wrong ?

Comment: No, not off-hand. Only thing I can think of would be to add a FF character (Form Feed) at the end ( `p.setData(0x0C)`) to eject the current page.

Comment: Thank you, but I managed to make it work by adding setDataStrobe() after the setData. I will write a proper answer tomorrow.